# Open source .NET DMS/CMS with API

Tags: .net, open-source, content-management-system

I'm looking for a recommendation on an open source .NET CMS framework. The CMS framework must ALSO be specifically targetted for document management. I've posted this as a new question to:

1. Hopefully get some fresh answers
2. I have some unique requirements

My requirements are:

1. NO UI necessary. Not a deal killer if it does have one...but I want to leverage it SOLELY for the API.
2. Should support document/content permissioning.
3. Should support document/content versioning.
4. Should use or be pluggable with a standard ASP .NET MembershipProvider/RoleProvider for authentication/authorization.
5. Rich API (especially since I won't be leveraging the UI) for uploading/downloading content, permissioning, etc..
6. Should be easily pluggable into an existing ASP .NET website.
7. Should be actively maintained (of course).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find something like this?  I am looking for the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's new solution to this: http://www.orchardproject.net/

Comment: Updated requirements in question. I need something for document management.